# How to use produced tf.keras(for tf version>2) model in C++

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, keras, inference

I am using https://github.com/fizyr/keras-retinanet this implementation of retinanet which is implemented with tensorflow and keras. So I want to use produced model in c++ for inference. But when I search for it, I can't find anything to try for tensorflow version>=2.0 . There is a good documentation for this operation for pytorch https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_export.html . I am looking for tensorflow version of it. Thanks.